# How do I get rid of this "double tab" effect on Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox

I have Firefox multi-account containers and Firefox temporary containers on my browser.

I like multi-accounts because it saves my login information for sites like SE, but I like having every session in a new containers so that I don't get followed around online.

I'm getting this weird effect though. Any time I open a new tab, it quickly closes and re-opens.

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Here's a video: https://streamable.com/ga22t

Comment: I'm seeing this with the Firefox Facebook Container too. It seems to be closing the "normal" tab and opening a different kind of tab. In their [official video for Firefox Containers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gy7lyvAfOSw) I'm not seeing this effect although it could be edited or just happening too fast to show up. I couldn't find an issue about this on their [GitHub](https://github.com/mozilla/multi-account-containers/issues) but perhaps you could open a new one

Comment: I'd do as MC10 suggested and open an issue about it.