# How do I customize Firefox hotkeys?

Tags: macos, firefox

I'm on Mac and the Firefox hotkey to go to the first tab is CMD + 1.

I'd like to change it to CTRL + 1. It looks like I can do it with the [Saka Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/saka-key/).

Can I change the hotkeys without in the config file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It seems like it is not possible at this time](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=57805). This enhancement was requested 19 years ago and it is still open. [On Mozilla Support's website](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly) they recommend using Sera key to change your keyboard shortcuts, but no further instructions are given to modify a config file.

Comment: It looks like Saka Key might be out of development. I downloaded it and the preferences and about page lead to 404s. https://key.saka.io/tutorial

Comment: Try this link for the tutorial : https://key.saka.io/docs/tutorial/setup
For the github repo : https://github.com/lusakasa/saka-key

Comment: Could you take a look at this post? https://superuser.com/questions/1424435/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-double-tab-effect-on-firefox