# Can I hide native tabs at the top of Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox

I've started using [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) on Firefox. It's a great solution for cases where you have many, many tabs and you want to add some level of organization to it.

It's becoming increasingly unnecessary to have the list of tabs on the top of my browser.

Is it possible to hide the list of tabs at the top of the browser?

Comment: I highly recommend this to anyone. It's such a better, simpler browsing experience.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To hide the native tabs, you'll have to add a new file called `userChrome.css` and the css property `visibility: collapse`.

To do this, in Firefox click on Click on `Menu -> Help -> More Troubleshooting Information` or navigate to `about:support` in the address bar.

Under the `Application Basics` section, there will be a section called `Profile Folder` with a button to `Open Directory`.

In the `Profile Directory` create a new folder called `chrome`. In the `chrome` folder create or edit the file `userChrome.css` if it already exists.

The contents of `userChrome.css` should be the following.

```
/* hides the native tabs */
#TabsToolbar {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

---

Some optional further modifications to put in `userChrome.css` are:

```
/* hides the title bar */
#titlebar {
  visibility: collapse;
}

/* hides the sidebar */
#sidebar-header {
  visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

A configuration that [Xilin Sun](https://medium.com/@Aenon/firefox-hide-native-tabs-and-titlebar-f0b00bdbb88b) uses is:

```
/* hides the native tabs */
#TabsToolbar {
  visibility: collapse;
}
/* leaves space for the window buttons */
#nav-bar {
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-right: 74px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}
```

Try these out and see what you think looks best.

---

To answer your question in the comment, you may like this option better. I tried using visibility, but it was extremely flashy and jittery with the hover.

```
/* Option 1 */
#TabsToolbar {
    opacity: 0.0;
}

#TabsToolbar:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
}

/* Option 2 */
#TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse;
}

#navigator-toolbox:hover #TabsToolbar {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

---

Before you close and relaunch, you must open `about:config` and toggle the property `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true` for this to be enabled.

Comment: Thanks! This looks great. Just curious, why is there a folder called Chrome in Firefox?

Comment: @Cauder I'm not sure, I was wondering the same thing. You could try to rename it and see if it still works.

Comment: Interesting, looks like there's no relationship with Google Chrome. https://www.nngroup.com/articles/browser-and-gui-chrome/

Comment: Is there any way I can switch back and forth? I tried it out and I realized it's nice when I have lots of tabs, but when I have few tabs I like to have the list  available at the top of the window.

Comment: @Cauder which contents did you put in your userChrome.css file?

Comment: I put just the options for #TabsToolbar and I put them into the root profile directory.

Comment: @Cauder Check the bottom of the answer. I have an update to it that you may like better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92347/discussion-between-drzoo-and-cauder).

Comment: Could you take a look at this post? https://superuser.com/questions/1424435/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-double-tab-effect-on-firefox

Comment: As of Firefox 69 (late 2019), you also must go to `about:config`, and change the value of `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `true`. I learned this in the comments of the post by Xilin Sun. Then quit and restart Firefox.

Comment: About "Chrome": I'm guessing that Firefox developers considered user CSS modifications to be like chrome bumpers on 1950s cars: pretty but not affecting function.

Comment: Does not work for me in Firefox 80.0.1 :(. Win 10

Comment: @edvard_munch check Will's answer below and see if that works.

Comment: @Cauder Because historically the Browser UI that is outside of the viewport is called "chrome". The term goes back to the netscape age. Analogy is to how the chrome on classic cars is the accents around the edges of the vehicle.

Comment: Superb! I was using Vivaldi mainly for this reason. Now I have the interface exactly how I want it.

Comment: Super, this worked the first time, I used the Xilin Sun config

Answer (score 25):

### Re-enable Custom CSS

1. Visit `about:config`
2. Search `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
3. Toggle it, making the value `true`

### Create userChrome.css

1. Visit `about:support`
2. To the right of "Profile Folder", press the button `Open Directory`
3. Create a new folder named `chrome`
4. Open the `chrome` folder and create a new file named `userChrome.css`

### Set the styling in userChrome.css

Different CSS needs to be used depending on whether you have the titlebar enabled.

#### With Titlebar

Titlebar visible *(Hamburger menu at top-right -> <kbd>More Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Customize Toolbar..</kbd>)*
[image]

Result *(Ubuntu screenshot)*
[image]

1. Inside the `userChrome.css` file, insert the code below to hide tabs:

```
#TabsToolbar {
  visibility: collapse;
}
```

2. Close and reopen Firefox to see the changes.

#### Without Titlebar

Titlebar not visible *(Hamburger menu at top-right -> <kbd>More Tools</kbd> -> <kbd>Customize Toolbar..</kbd>)*
[image]

Result *(Ubuntu screenshot)*
[image]

1. Inside the `userChrome.css` file, insert the code below to hide tabs:

```
#tabbrowser-tabs {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```

2. Close and reopen Firefox to see the changes.

---

### Alternative Styling

#### Without Titlebar: Mini bar

*Result (Ubuntu)*
[image]

*Styling*

```
#tabbrowser-tabs {
    visibility: collapse;
}
#titlebar {
    max-height: 16px;
}
#TabsToolbar .titlebar-buttonbox-container {
    transform: scale(.55) translateY(-10px) translateX(38px);
}
```

#### Without Titlebar: Drag Space Only (No Window Buttons)

*Result (Ubuntu)*
[image]

*Styling*

```
#tabbrowser-tabs {
    visibility: collapse;
}
#titlebar {
    max-height: 5px;
}
#TabsToolbar .titlebar-buttonbox-container {
    display: none;
}
```

#### Without Titlebar: Inline Window Buttons (With Drag Box)

*Result (Ubuntu)*
[image]
[image]

*Styling*

```
#tabbrowser-tabs {
    visibility: collapse;
}
#navigator-toolbox {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
#titlebar {
    order: 1;
    max-width: 146px;
}
#titlebar #TabsToolbar {
    background-color: var(--toolbar-bgcolor);
    background-image: var(--toolbar-bgimage)
}
#titlebar #TabsToolbar .titlebar-spacer {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 25%;
    cursor: grab;
}
#titlebar #TabsToolbar .titlebar-spacer[type="pre-tabs"] {
    display: none;
}
#nav-bar {
    order: 0;
    width: calc(100% - 146px);
}
#PersonalToolbar {
    order: 2;
}
/* Update - Hides the new Firefox home + tab dropdown. If you want to keep/customize those buttons. remove the CSS below and adjust the widths above to get everything fitting in one line */
#TabsToolbar .toolbar-items {
  display: none;
}
```

For MacOS, you can also set

```css
#nav-bar {
    order: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This will move the window buttons on the bookmarks tab, making the top bar look more complete.

#### Tweaking these custom styles

You don't have to guess and check the styling. Firefox has a devtools window for the browser itself. It's called "Browser Toolbox", but looks identical to Firefox's website devtools.

Mozilla has info on how to use that here: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/browser_toolbox/index.html

**The TL;DR is:** Open Devtools -> Go to settings -> Check "Enable browser chrome and add-on debugging" and "Enable remote debugging" -> Use `Ctrl + Shift + Alt + i` to launch it.

Comment: +1. Worked in FF 85.

Comment: This is the perfect answer.

Comment: +1 for telling us that we first need to enable toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets to use custom css

Comment: Great updated answer; I especially appreciate the custom templates (which also work decently well on Windows as of January 2023).

Comment: Amazing, worked on Ubuntu 20.04 with FF 112.0.2 (64-bit), by only copy-pasting! So much less visual clutter now!

Comment: For me only the `chrome/userChrome.css` would execute when this folder and file is located within `AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/profiles/<profile_name>`

Answer (score 15):

If you're running Windows 10, I've found the following gives the best integration:

[image: screenshot of windows 10 tab integration]

1. Enable "Title Bar" mode by going to the hamburger menu (☰) → Customize → Check the "Title Bar" checkbox at the bottom of the screen.
2. Apply the following [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org/how-create-userchrome-css.html):

```css
#main-window[tabsintitlebar="true"]:not([extradragspace="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#main-window:not([tabsintitlebar="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning how to enable "Title Bar" mode.

Answer (score 6):

Having gone through most of the solutions in this thread, here is my personal recommendation if you want to achieve following:

- Use Tree Style Tab and want to hide horizontal tabs
- Show a window handler because you need to move a lot
- Across macOS and Windows 10

> [image: macOS]
>
> macOS

> [image: Windows 10]
>
> Windows 10

---

#### Step 1: Enable CSS

1. Visit `about:config` → Click `Accept the Risk and Continue`
2. Search `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
3. Toggle it, making the value `true`

#### Step 2: Find CSS

1. Visit `about:support` in the address bar
2. Find table `Application Basics` → find row `Profile Folder` → click  button `Show in Folder` or `Open Folder`. It usually points to

   - `/Users/your-alias/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/your-id.Default User` for macOS
   - *Or* `C:\Users\your-alias\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\your-id.Default User` for Windows
3. In this Profile Folder create a new folder called `chrome` or open it if it already exsits.
4. In the `chrome` folder create `userChrome.css` or edit it if it already exists.

#### Step 3: Edit CSS

1. Edit `userChrome.css` and please add:

```
/* To hide horizontal bars */
#main-window[tabsintitlebar="true"]:not([extradragspace="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

#main-window:not([tabsintitlebar="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

2. (*Optional*) If you want to have a smaller header of `Tree Style Tab` on the sidebar, please add:

```
/* For Tree Style Tab */
#sidebar-header{
  font-size: 1em !important;
  padding: 5px 2px 5px 13px !important;
}
```

#### Step 4: Enable title Bar and restart

1. Enable "Title Bar" mode

   - Right click on Toolbar → select `Customize Toolbar...`
   - *Or* by Click the menu (☰) → `More tools` → `Customize Toolbar...`
2. At the left bottom of the screen, check the "Title Bar" checkbox → Submit right bottom button `Done`
3. Restart.

Comment: This was the solution that worked for me!

Answer (score 4):

This css removes tabs, but preserves menu and minimize/maximize/close buttons.

```
#tabbrowser-tabs {  visibility: collapse;}
```

Works in FF version 83

Comment: Thanks this is what I am looking for.

Comment: Thanks, fast and easy. It works fine on Debian 11 and FF 91.6.1esr

Comment: For me this removes the tabs but not the #TabsToolbar that contains them and so you're left (or I was in FF 106.0 on Kubuntu 22.04.1) with an empty bar. So, not tabs, but not quite what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my favorite setup for macOS Monterey.

[image: titlebar]

First [follow these steps](https://superuser.com/a/1619663/4525) to get userChrome.css enabled.

Then add this to userChrome.css

```css
#tabbrowser-tabs {
  visibility: collapse;
}

#titlebar #TabsToolbar {
  background-color: var(--toolbar-bgcolor);
  background-image: var(--toolbar-bgimage);
  padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Finally, remove the space between Refresh button and url bar.

- Right click on empty area of toolbar and select Customize.
- Drag spacer from between the refresh button and url bar off the toolbar.
- Done

Answer (score 1):

Ok so this took me a while because for me the window buttons always started to disappear as soon as I "collapsed" the TabsToolBar. After some research I found a solution on a moz support forum that enabled me to hide the native tabs while still maintaining the window min/max/close buttons and having some space to move the window without having a big empty title bar. (As now this will work in Firefox V107.0.1 on Windows10)

To do so here is the CSS to put in your "userChrome.css" after you set the "toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets" option to True in your about:config section.

```
#main-window[tabsintitlebar="true"]:not([extradragspace="true"]) #TabsToolbar > .toolbar-items {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#main-window:not([tabsintitlebar="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse !important;
}

#titlebar {
    max-height: 1px;
}

#nav-bar {
    margin-top: -30px;
    margin-right: 146px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

Now you will also have to add a "flexible space" to your toolbar to have some room to move the window. (Right click anywhere click on customize and drag in into your desired place) This resulted in a Window that was good for me looking like this:

[image: Window Top Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a report of my results and favorite userChrome.css contents on Mac OS Ventura:

Result:
[image: Mac Tiny Title Bar with Window Buttons]

Code:

```
#main-window[tabsintitlebar="true"]:not([extradragspace="true"]) #TabsToolbar > .toolbar-items {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#main-window:not([tabsintitlebar="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
    visibility: collapse !important;
}

#titlebar {
    max-height: 15px;
}

/* For Tree Style Tab */
#sidebar-header{
  font-size: 1em !important;
  padding: 5px 2px 5px 13px !important;
}
```

Results in a tiny title bar with just enough room for the mac window buttons.  No top tabs, and no large empty area where the tabs used to be.

+1 for info on live debugging the userChrome.css file.

I also found the following easier step-by-step instructions for live-debugging userChrome.css:

https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/73dvty/tutorial_how_to_create_and_livedebug_userchromecss/

Comment: This is in Firefox 120.0.1

Answer (score 0):

A "low-code" solution is to use MrOtherGuy's Firefox CSS stylesheets: https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks

After following the [setup guide](https://github.com/MrOtherGuy/firefox-csshacks?tab=readme-ov-file#setup) (same as other answers here, to enable custom stylesheets and create the `chrome` directory in Profile) I created a `userChrome.css` file with the following content (and downloaded the referenced files into the same directory):

```css
@import url(window_control_placeholder_support.css);
@import url(hide_tabs_toolbar_osx.css);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just press F11 to go full screen. It takes away the native tabs bar among others.

Comment: Yes, “among others” — such as the (Windows) menu bar, the address bar, the Firefox tools and the bookmarks bar.  A little like burning down your house to get rid of termites.