# Can I hide native tabs at the top of Firefox 91.51 esr (64 bit)?

Tags: macos, firefox, tabs, tree

I've been using [Tree Style Tab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) on Firefox. Not sure how I ever worked without. There was a similar post [(found here)](https://superuser.com/questions/1424478/can-i-hide-native-tabs-at-the-top-of-firefox/1702567#1702567) that allowed the top tabs to be hidden, but it seems like that is no longer working.

Here are a few examples of what I have tried for my .css file:

```
/* hides the native tabs */
#TabsToolbar {
visibility: collapse;
}
```

AND

```
main-window[tabsintitlebar="true"]:not([extradragspace="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
opacity: 0;
pointer-events: none;
}
#main-window:not([tabsintitlebar="true"]) #TabsToolbar {
visibility: collapse !important;
}
```

Is it still possible to hide the list of top tabs? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and wanted to post the answer here for anyone who struggled as i did. The answer was actually in the original post that I linked above, but I did not understand how to get there. In addition to creating the CCS file, you have to enable the custom CCS.

1. Visit the about config page by typing `about:config` into your browsers address bar and hitting enter.
2. Search `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets`
3. Toggle it, making the value true

Close and reopen firefox and your top tabs should be gone.