# How to hide native tabs in Firefox 100.0; existing answers are out of date?

Tags: firefox, css

There are multiple questions of this (of which, [this seems to be the parent](https://superuser.com/questions/1424478/can-i-hide-native-tabs-at-the-top-of-firefox)) but they are all out of date.

I set `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` to `True` and tried this text in chrome/userChrome.css

```
/* hides the native tabs */
#TabsToolbar {
visibility: collapse;
}
```

In Firefox 100.0, this does not seem to be working. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears they have changed the name of the id. It is now `TabsToolbar-customization-target`.

This should work for `userChrome.css`:

```
#TabsToolbar-customization-target {
    visibility: collapse;
}
```