# Using the Firefox Browser Toolbox and style sheets to hide UI elements

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I am trying to hide the button circled in red prompting me to install a new search engine (which that one, brave, is already installed, so WTF?)  However, I have no way to select it with the Browser Toolbox element picker, because it is inside the search bar and once a mouseclick is detected elsewhere, it closes.

So I guess my first question is, how am I supposed to select such a thing in order to get the element info.  And then how do I remove that element using a userchrome.css file (which is already enabled and ready to use)?

[image: imgur]

Answer (score 0):

To inspect elements or popups that disappear when you click elsewhere, you can select the option from the three-dot menu on the right to `Disable Popup Auto-Hide`.

[image: Disable Popup Auto-Hide]

Comment: Thanks, but now that I found the element, what do I need to write in userchrome.css to hide it?

Comment: @Matt Usually just `display: none`, you may need to include [`!important`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/important) if something is overriding it. It depends on the element, sometimes [`collapse`](https://superuser.com/questions/1720151/how-to-hide-native-tabs-in-firefox-100-0-existing-answers-are-out-of-date/1756337#1756337)