# Can I get rid of the search suggestion on Firefox?

Tags: macos, firefox

Is it possible to do searches on Firefox without getting the search suggestions?

I've already set it up so that it doesn't use my browser history for suggestions. I'm curious if I can change Firefox so there isn't a box at all. I use the same browser every time, so it's unnecessary.

Everything I'm seeing online is about getting rid of suggestions, but I can't find anything on getting rid of the box altogether. I did use a filter on uBlock Origin to get rid of it on Youtube.

I'd like to get rid of the dropdown box altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize almost any part of the UI in Firefox with [userChrome.css](http://kb.mozillazine.org/index.php?title=UserChrome.css) (if anyone is wondering why Firefox has a folder called `chrome`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Chrome)

It's just the matter of finding the right element. It took a while to find but the id of the panel that appears from the search bar is `PopupSearchAutoComplete`.

```
#PopupSearchAutoComplete
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

This should do the trick. I hope this is what you're after, if not just let me know.

If your address and search bars are combined, it should be `PopupAutoCompleteRichResult`.

```
#PopupAutoCompleteRichResult
{
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Is there a list with all the elements? I applied that CSS to the .chrome file, but I'm still getting the popup

Comment: I'm not sure of a list, there are way too many elements. You can use the [Browser Toolbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Toolbox) to inspect and find elements. Just to confirm, the box you want to hide comes from the search bar or the address bar?

Comment: I have the two bars set as the same bar in my Firefox instance.

Comment: @Cauder Oh I see, I have it that way on my home computer but I was at work when I answered. The id should be `PopupAutoCompleteRichResult` in that case

Comment: For non-programmers, this would be more useful if you add instructions for where and how to make the change (unless it's a bad idea for people to be messing with this if they don't know what they're doing).

Comment: Not sure if this is something only programmers would be capable of, but good point I've added the Mozilla reference for userChrome.css. My answer was geared towards OP's specific case but wasn't suitable for a general audience

Comment: Years of going through Chrome's incessant nagging and you helped create a Firefox that is peaceful and quiet. Thank you.

Comment: If you get a chance, could you take a look at this post https://superuser.com/questions/1424435/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-double-tab-effect-on-firefox

Comment: Did Firefox get rid of the chrome folder? I installed the browser on a new computer and I don't see it inside my profile directory.

Comment: @Cauder Did you resolve chrome folder thing? A new installation likely won't have it. If it doesn't exist, you can create it yourself, along with the userChrome file(s).

Answer (score 0):

In `about:preferences#search`, you can uncheck `Provide search suggestions` in the `Default Search Engine` section. With this, you only have a maximum of two lines in the box, the `Visit` and the `Search` buttons.

Comment: Please see my edit to the post.